# Trouble removing elements from C++ vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to remove 'dead' bullets from my vector of bullets. Every frame, I'm calling the Bullet::update() function which looks like this:

```
    void Bullet::update()
{
    for(int i = 0; i != mAmmo.size(); i++)
    {
        if(mAmmo[i].sprite.getPosition().x > 700)
            mAmmo[i].mAlive = false;
        if(mAmmo[i].mAlive == false)
        {
// I get a Debug Assertion Failed at runtime from this piece of code
            mAmmo.erase(mAmmo.begin()+i);
        }

        if(mAmmo[i].mAlive == true)
        {
            mAmmo[i].sprite.move(mMovement);
        }

    }

}
```

Am I doing this completely incorrectly? This is the first time I've really used vectors more than just following through a tutorial. If I need to post any more code, just tell me. I've been working on this for the past few hours, so I'm a wee bit desperate to get this to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A funny thing (or in this case not-so-funny) happened to that vector when you erased the element at `i` and it happened to be the *last* element. You should be using iterators for this and your true-test should be *first*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're easily walking into undefined behavior as soon as the `i`th element is the *last* element in your list. Use iterators, and pay special attention to the return value of [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase), as it automatically advances the iterator for you so your loop doesn't have to.

```
void Bullet::update()
{
    for (auto it = mAmmo.begin(); it != mAmmo.end();)
    {
        if(it->sprite.getPosition().x > 700)
            it->mAlive = false;

        if (!it->mAlive)
        {
            // erase and get next iterator
            it = mAmmo.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {   // move and increment
            it->sprite.move(mMovement);
            ++it;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason I didn't use an iterator is because I don't fully understand them. Looks like I know what I'm researching tonight, thanks!

Comment: It will change the way you do many things in C++ using the standard library, to be sure. As you research, pay *very* close attention to member functions of containers that specific state "invalidates all existing iterators..." And if you need a content reference, [this is really at the top](http://www.cppreference.com) as far as I'm concerned.